# Character Limit In Text Area JavaScript - Special Case

Tags: javascript

I have a blocker in my way, where I have to limit the users to enter characters more than the limit in a custom text area tag. In our application, we are counting **ENTER as 5 characters** and any other **SPECIAL CHARACTERS as 5 characters** too. Once the limit is reached, we are suppose to block the user to type in any more characters without any alerts.

**Here is what I have tried so far:**

```
    function maxLengthVal(ele,length){
        var textSize = ele.value.length;

        if(textSize >= length){
            ele.value = ele.value.substring(0, length);
        }           
    }
```

This is the function what i am calling on onKeyup and Onkeydown. Right now it is only counting the characters, but does not consider ENTER or SPECIAL CHARACTERS as 5 characters.

I need a similar one, but with the 5 characters parsing in it. I am stuck on how to approach it. If someone can help that will be great.

Comment: In your function, determine what key was pressed (there are plenty of examples on how to get which key was pressed in javascript on the web), if it is 13 (which I believe is Enter), then set `textSize = ele.value.length + 5;`, else, set it to `ele.value.length;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function maxLengthVal(ele,length) {
    var textSize = length_SPECIAL(value);

    if (textSize >= length) {
        ele.value = ele.value.substring(0, length);
    }           
}
```

Where `length_SPECIAL` is:

```
function length_SPECIAL(str) {
    function is_SPECIAL(charCode) {
        switch(charCode) {
            case 13: case 9: /* etc... */
                return true;
        }

         return false;
    }

    var cnt = 0;

    for (var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        cnt += (is_SPECIAL(str.charCodeAt(i)) ? 5 : 1);
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <textarea id="demo"></textarea>
        <span class="count"></span>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'd suggest:

```
function characterCount() {
    // caching the relevant element (passed in
    // automagically from addEventListener()):
    var self = this,
        // finding the element in which the count
        // should be displayed:
        output = self.parentNode.querySelector('.count'),
        // the value of the <textarea>:
        val = self.value,
        // a simple regular expression that matches all
        // non-word characters (equivalent to: [^A-Za-z0-9_],
        // so not A-z, a-z, 0-9 or underscore); this should
        // be replaced by whatever list of characters you
        // consider 'special':
        reg = /\W/g,
        // removing all the 'special' characters, by
        // replacing them with empty strings, and getting
        // the length of that non-special characters string:
        normalCount = val.replace(reg, '').length,

        // finding all the 'special' characters:
        specials = val.match(/\W/g),

        // if there were some 'special' characters found 
        // (String.match() returns null if there are no
        // matches found, or an array if matches are found)
        // we get the length of that array of matches, or
        // zero (to ensure a numerical value):
        specialCount = specials ? specials.length : 0;

    // setting the textContent to the result of normalCount
    // plus the number of 'special' characters multiplied
    // by 5:
    output.textContent = normalCount + (specialCount * 5);
}

// getting the textarea (via its id):
var textarea = document.querySelector('#demo');

// binding the characterCount function
// as the keyup event-handler:
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', characterCount);
```

```js
function characterCount() {
  var self = this,
    output = self.parentNode.querySelector('.count'),
    val = self.value,
    reg = /\W/g,
    normalCount = val.replace(reg, '').length,
    specials = val.match(/\W/g),
    specialCount = specials ? specials.length : 0;

  output.textContent = normalCount + (specialCount * 5);
}

var textarea = document.querySelector('#demo');

textarea.addEventListener('keyup', characterCount);
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <textarea id="demo"></textarea>
    <span class="count"></span>

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qj4vv3ws/).

References:

- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelector).
- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- [Guide to JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).
- [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).
- [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: This seems to be good but it doesn't seem to be working for below IE 10 because of the event listener I guess. Dominiques answer seems to be working fine. Thanks for your effort. Let me know if there is any solution to this.